# AAD B2C always have to input credentials when running login user flow

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am new to using AAD B2C and I am confused why I always have to input my credentials when running the login user flow. Does this mean that I am always logged out whenever I go to the user flow uri?

Moreover, I am also confused on how to implement the login flow. Here is my understanding:

1. I login using the login user flow uri (a button with href value of the login user flow uri)
2. I get the *id_token* from callback
3. Use the token for authorization?
4. Use the endpoints?

I will be using AAD B2C for multiple apps on the same tenant, with SSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there prompt=login parameter in the URL query string when the user flow is opened? This might be the reason as it forces entering credentials.

Comment: Hello, I tried removing the prompt=login part on the URL and indeed it didn't let me enter the credentials. But it still lets me login when I open the same user flow but from another app. This is not what SSO is for me, in my own understanding. Am I right?

EDIT: Oh wait, my bad, I doesn't let me enter my credentials when opening the same user flow on the same app, but on a different redirect link.

Comment: Update: it let me enter my credentials because it had mfa enabled, after entering the code from a text message, any recurring calls after that did not require the credentials anymore.

Comment: Have you checked session behaviour settings? The default SSO scope is "Tenant". You might want to scope it down to Application or Policy, depending on the setup you have. You can find it in Policy settings:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior

Answer (score 0):

In terms of "implementing the login flow", use one of the [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples) as appropriate.

There are full details of how to hook them up to your custom policy.